# Heroku MySQL Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, heroku

I am using ClearDB for a mysql database. I have a table with an auto incremented primary key. The problem is that rather than it incrementing by 1, its incrementing by 10. How can I fix this please?

Also when I tested the db on local host, the incrementation was working correctly.

EDIT: I also tried to use the command: 'SET @@auto_increment_increment=1', but it didnt work. Im not sure if I am doing it right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#general_16

auto-increment keys are partitioned between instances to prevent collision.

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary? I understand that it's important to avoid conflicts like updating the same rows on different servers but I don't understand why incrementing by the number of masters there is eliminates collisions.

Comment: that link is broken :(