# MySQL auto_increment 10 instead of 1 when using spring jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, auto-increment, spring-jdbc, mysql-connector

I have been following this guide for a personnal project and I am facing this weird problem : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm

When inserting values with spring jdbc library, the id's values jump from 1 to 11 to 21... etc. Although, when manually querying the database with a simple insert, the id are working as intended, ie : 1,2,3, etc...

Here is the infos :

spring-jdbc 4.2.3
spring-context 4.3.3
mysql-connector-java 5.1.37

Database : MySQL Community Server(GPL) 5.5.45-log hosted on Azure with ClearDB add on.

Create table  :

```
CREATE TABLE runners(
   id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   location VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

When I am querying : `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` , I get :
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1

Here is the code :

Runner.java

```
public class Runner{
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String location;

    public Integer getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public String getLocation(){
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location){
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

RunnerDAO.java

```
public interface RunnerDAO {

       public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);

       public void create(String firstName, String lastName, String location);

       public Runner getRunner(Integer id);

       public List<Runner> listRunners();

       public void delete(Integer id);

       public void update(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String location);
}
```

RunnerJDBCTEmplate.java

```
public class RunnerJDBCTemplate implements RunnerDAO {
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }

   public void create(String firstName, String lastName, String location) {
      String SQL = "insert into runners (firstName, lastName,location) values (?, ?, ?)";

      jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, firstName, lastName, location);
      System.out.println("Created Record FirstName = " + firstName + " LastName = " + lastName+ " Location = " + location);
      return;
   }

   public Runner getRunner(Integer id) {
      String SQL = "select * from runners where id = ?";
      Runner runner = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{id}, new RunnerMapper());
      return runner;
   }

   public List<Runner> listRunners() {
      String SQL = "select * from runners";
      List <Runner> runners = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL,new RunnerMapper());
      return runners;
   }

   public void delete(Integer id){
      String SQL = "delete from runners where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
      System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }

   public void update(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String location){
      String SQL = "update runners set firstName = ?,lastName = ?, location = ? where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, firstName, lastName, location , id);
      System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }
}
```

RunnerMapper.java

```
public class RunnerMapper implements RowMapper<Runner> {
   public Runner mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Runner runner = new Runner();
      runner.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
      runner.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
      runner.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
      runner.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));
      return runner;
   }
}
```

When I run this main.java :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

          RunnerJDBCTemplate runnerJDBCTemplate = 
          (RunnerJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("RunnerJDBCTemplate");

          System.out.println("------Records Creation--------" );
          runnerJDBCTemplate.create("John", "Doe", "1234 street");
          runnerJDBCTemplate.create("Jane", "Dude", "5678 boulevard");
          runnerJDBCTemplate.create("Johnny", "Duh", "111 avenue");
    }
}
```

I get the following output in my database

```
1   John    Doe 1234 street
11  Jane    Dude    5678 boulevard
21  Johnny  Duh 111 avenue
```

I tried `SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;`

Again, when querying manually everything is fine.

Somebody has a clue ? Thanks !

**EDIT**

I tried an other mysql hosting and now it works perfectly. It seems like Azure ClearDb Addon is the source of the problem. Still, if someone has an explanation, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Azure is using the same ClearDB as Heroku. So the this answer here is the best explanation [Heroku MySQL Auto Increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078288/heroku-mysql-auto-increment)

In short, it's a ClearDB strategy to prevent collision http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#general_16

Answer (score 1):

Try running the "SET @@auto_increment_increment=0" *in your code*, rather than running it manually.  Make sure you run it, before running any DML.

By the way, you can investigate the root cause, by logging every query that is being sent to MySQL, via:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

-- run your java code, and wait for it to finish

SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log;
```

This gives you the queries that have been executed by your code (or any other code running in the background).